# Handling M:N-relationships in C# with Lists

Tags: c#, .net, postgresql

Im working on a project where I have three tables in my postgres-DB. Person, Group, and group_leader.

How would you handle this M:N-relationship in C#? I am currently looping through my datareader and creating objects of both groups and persons, where groups has a list of persons, and persons has a list of groups.

Do I need to make an intersection class to the information about which person is the leader of which group? And how do I get the information about which person is leading which group?

Do I need a separate class "Leader" where I query about which person is leader of which group and hold a list of this in one of the classes? So maybe Group has a list of leaders?

What is the best practice?

```
public class person
{
    public int personid { get; set; }
    public string firstname { get; set; }
    public string lastname { get; set; }

    public List<group> group { get; set; }

    public person()
    {
        group = new List<group>();
    }
}
```

Group-Class:

```
public class group
{
    public List<person> personlista { get; set; }
    public int groupid { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public DateTime start { get; set; }
    public DateTime end { get; set; }

    public group()
    {
        personlista = new List<person>();
    }


    public void NewMember(person NewPerson)
    {
        MemberOfThisGroup.Add(NewPerson);
    }
}
```

Comment: Do you have a set database schema that you are doing this off of?

Comment: Hi, yes Ive made an ERD for this. Basically Person has personID, group has GroupID, and then group_leader contains both these values. In SQL I have no problems getting the leaders for each group. But what Im wondering is how I will manage this in my application?

Comment: Property should be of type ICollection, not List. List implies order, which is not an aspect of M : N relationship

Comment: OK, but what about the main question. What is the way to handle these relationships?